# MUI (Material UI) Toggle Button Group useState Hook in React.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following in my App.js:

```
import { Box } from "@mui/system";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import ProjectList from "./components/ProjectList";
import CardLayout from "./components/CardLayout";
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [view, setView] = useState("list");

  const handleView = (event, newView) => {
    setView(newView);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Header view={view} onChange={handleView} />
      <ProjectList />
      <CardLayout />
    </Box>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The goal is to render only the ProjectList component when the toggle button with value list is selected `<ToggleButton value={props.list}>` and render only CardLayout component when the toggle button with value grid is selected `<ToggleButton value={props.grid}>`

My Header.js component (button section) is this:

```
  <ToggleButtonGroup
    size="large"
    value={props.view}
    onChange={props.onChange}
    exclusive
  >
    <ToggleButton value={props.list}>
      <TableRowsIcon />
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton value={props.grid}>
      <GridViewIcon />
    </ToggleButton>
  </ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Am I passing in the props from parent to child correctly? What should the `setView` function be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone reading this in the future, I figured it out:
The toggle button group should look like this:

```
<ToggleButtonGroup
            size="large"
            value={props.view}
            exclusive
            onChange={props.onSetView}
          >
            <ToggleButton value="list">
              <TableRowsIcon />
            </ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton value="grid">
              <GridViewIcon />
            </ToggleButton>
          </ToggleButtonGroup>
```

And in the App.js the setViewHandler has to have this if condition in order for the toggle to work properly:

```
  const setViewHandler = (event, newView) => {
    if (newView !== null) {
      setView(newView);
    }
    console.log(view);
  };
```

Then, you simply pass this function as a prop to the child component where the button is located.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use conditional rendering to achieve this.

For example, in your `App.js`, change this:

```
<ProjectList />
```

to this:

```
{ view == list ?? <ProjectList /> }
```

That will render `<ProjectList />` ONLY IF `view == list`. You will need to create another state to handle the CardLayout rendering.

More information about conditional rendering can be found on the official docs: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn#conditional-rendering

Comment: Thanks! the ?? didn't work for some reason so I ended up using a normal ternary operation

Comment: this format  **value??otherValue**  means 
`if value !==undifind then value else otherValue`

Answer (score 1):

- I think instead this code `<ToggleButton value={props.list}>` you must write `<ToggleButton value='List'>` because 'list' is value not property
- if you use class components don't forget **this.** before props in the header component

Comment: That's right thanks for the correction